# Using Different Session Namespaces with Zend Framework 2 Authentication Component

Tags: session, authentication, zend-framework2

I'm planning to use ZF2 in a future project, so I'm trying Zend Framework 2 RC1 now. I started with authentication step, and noticed that when i chose a different name than 'Zend_Auth' for session storage namespace, i can't access to object stored in session (AuthenticationService class' hasIdentity method returned false, despite User object data set in session).

```
<?php
namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Authentication\Adapter\DbTable as AuthAdapter;
use Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService;
use Zend\Authentication\Storage\Session as SessionStorage;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Application\Model\User;
use Application\Form\LoginForm;

class LoginController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $auth = new AuthenticationService();

        if ($auth->hasIdentity()) {
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('application');
        }

        $form = new LoginForm();
        return array('form' => $form);
    }

    public function loginAction()
    {
        $auth = new AuthenticationService();

        $form = new LoginForm();
        $form->get('submit')->setAttribute('value', 'Add');

        $request = $this->getRequest();

        if ($request->isPost()) {
            $user = new User();
            $form->setInputFilter($user->getInputFilter('login'));

            $form->setData($request->getPost());
            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $data = $form->getData();

                // Configure the instance with constructor parameters...
                $sm          = $this->getServiceLocator();
                $dbAdapter   = $sm->get('db-adapter');
                $authAdapter = new AuthAdapter($dbAdapter, 'users', 'username', 'password');

                $authAdapter
                    ->setIdentity($data['username'])
                    ->setCredential(sha1($data['password']));

                // Use 'users' instead of 'Zend_Auth'
                $auth->setStorage(new SessionStorage('users'));

                $result = $auth->authenticate($authAdapter);

                if ($result->isValid()) {
                    // store the identity as an object where only the username and
                    // real_name have been returned
                    $storage = $auth->getStorage();

                    // store the identity as an object where the password column has
                    // been omitted
                    $storage->write($authAdapter->getResultRowObject(
                        null,
                        'password'
                    ));

                    // Redirect to list of application
                    return $this->redirect()->toRoute('application');
                }
            }    
        }

        // processed if form is not valid
        return array('form' => $form);
    }
}
```

In this code, when i changed the below line,

```
$auth->setStorage(new SessionStorage('users'));
```

like this:

```
$auth->setStorage(new SessionStorage());
```

hasIdentity method returned true.

I checked two classes Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService and Zend\Authentication\Storage\Session, and didn't see a way to access session data which has different session namespace other than default.

What i need to understand is how can i access session data which has a different namespace and if there is no way to do it for now, should we define this as a bug?

I can update the question if any other information needed.

Answer (score 2):

We are kinda missing one part of your code, the one where you try and receive the user identity. im guessing that you have forgotten to pass the the SessionStorage Object with the same namespace.

Also the configuration of the Authentication object should be moved to a factory so these kind of issues to not arrise.

Thats my five cents atleast :)

Comment: Antoine Hedgecock, sorry for my late reply. The code which i try and receive user identity is indexAction for the above code. And yes, i didn't pass the SessionStorage object when i tried it with different namespace. Now i'm thinking that we have to pass SessionStorage object in order to use a different namespace than default _Zend_Auth_ namespace(as you mentioned in your answer), is this true? is there any other simple way to do this, perhaps passing namespace string to AuthenticationService class?